# ConnectivityManager in Android Application

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context

I'm using the following code, in Android application, for monitoring network connections.

```
 ConnectivityManager conMgr = 
       (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

This code works good if I'm in any Activity, while if I'm in a generic class I can't call
the method

> getSystemService

how can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to access `getSystemService` in Non Activity class then just pass Current Activity Context to Non Activity class by using Constructor as:

```
    public class nonActivity{

    Context context;
     ConnectivityManager conMgr ;

    pulblic nonActivity(Context context){

      this.context=context;

    // now get getSystemService as :
       this.conMgr = 
       (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

      }

 }
```

and pass Current Activity Context to non Activity class as:

```
nonActivity nonactivityobj=new nonActivity(Your_Current_Activity.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call generic class at that time you have to pass the **context of activity** in it.

So you can access `getSystemService`

**Code :-**

```
public class Test
{
    Context context;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager ;

    pulblic Test(Context context)
    {
      this.context=context;
      connectivityManager = 
      (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }
 }
```

and pass context as below from activity class.

```
Test test = new Test(CurrentActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Context instead of this, it will solve your problem and Write below line in class instead of your code line.

```
ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: I obtain this error: 

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getSystemService(String) from the type Context

Comment: Write this line in default constructor of class and pass context value as a parameter in default constructor